# If $ G $ is a finite group. Suppose $ 1 = G_{0} \unlhd G_{1} \unlhd \cdots \unlhd G_{s} = G $ is a chief series of $ G $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The $ p $-Fitting Subgroup of $ G $ is the maximal normal $ p $-nilpotent subgroup Of $ G $ and write it $ F_{p}(G) $.

If $ G $ is a finite group. Suppose $ 1 = G_{0} \unlhd G_{1} \unlhd \cdots \unlhd G_{s} = G $ is a chief series of $ G $.Then $ F_{p}(G) = \bigcap_{p \vert \vert G_{i+1}/G_{i} \vert} C_{G}(G_{i+1}/G_{i}) $ is $ p $-nilpotent, and $ F_{p}(G) $ contains all normal $ p $-nilpotent subgroup of $ G $.

proof: Let $ H $ be a normal $ p $-nilpotent subgroup of $ G $ and let $ N $ be a minimal normal subgroup of $ G $ whose order is divisible bye $ p $. Assume that $ [H , N] \neq 1 $. Then $ H \cap N \neq 1 $ and thus $ N \leq H $. Now $ N \nleq O_{p^{\prime}}(H) $, so that $ N \cap o_{p^{\prime}}(H) = 1 $.Hence $ N $ is a $ p $-group. Also $ O_{p^{\prime}}(H) \leq C_{H}(N) $ and $ \overline{H} = H / C_{H}(N) $ is a $ p $-group. The natural semidirect product $ \overline{H} \ltimes N $ is a $ p $-group, so it is nilpotent and $ [H , N] < N $. This implies that $ [h , N] = 1 $ since $ N $ is normal minimal in $ G $. I understand until here but I do not understand below. Please help me.

It follows by induction on $ \vert G \vert $ that $ H $ centralizers every principle factor whose order is divisible by $ p $?

Comment: If $K/L$ is such a chief factor, then you just apply the result you proved to $G/L$.